# Error while using Azure Mobile Apps - Javascript Client SDK

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I am developing ionic mobile app. I have followed these documents https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client and https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ContosoMoments/tree/master/src

When I inject 'mobileServicesClient' in my controller, I am getting unknown provider error.
If I use directly in function like this

```
var clientRef = new MobileServiceClient('https://******.azurewebsites.net');
clientRef.login('aad').then(function(result){ console.log(result); },function(result){ console.log(result); }
```

I am getting error : 'MobileServiceClient is not defined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using ionic framework to implement your client application, you can try to use [Apache Cordova plugin for Azure Mobile Apps](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-cordova-client) as the client SDK.

And especially to ionic based applications, you can refer to https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-mobile-apps-with-ionic for the starter example project of azure mobile apps with ionic.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: With  Apache Cordova plugin for Azure Mobile Apps, I was able to authenticated. I also found this https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mobileservices/MobileServices.Web-1.2.7.min.js for JavaScript SDK and its working. I want to build hybrid mobile apps. So JavaScript SDK would be better or client SDK ?

Comment: It is recommanded that for H5 application, to use JS SDK, and for mobile apps, to use client SDK. As you can find the SDK is divided into 2 platforms(`web` & `cordova`) in source code at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/tree/master/sdk/src/Platform. So There are almost the same in Authentication and table operations, but should be some platform specials.

Comment: For Cordova app, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library, and for H5 applications, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library

Comment: Thank you  so much for suggestions and comments

Answer (score 1):

Add script reference to your object before using it.

```
<script src="https://zumo.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0-rc1.js"></script>
```

And use correct namespace

```
var clientRef = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://...');
```

Comment: I tried with WindowsAzure also. But it gives same error WindowsAzure is not defined. I have used  azure-mobile-apps-client.js instead of azure-mobile-apps-client.2.0.0-rc1.js. Is there any difference between them? On github , I found it (not 2.0.0)as latest.

Comment: Seems this lib is not released yet. See lib version in npm `npm show azure-mobile-apps-client version` - it shows only *2.0.0-rc1* is available now. So seems you can't use strict '2.0.0' yet.

Comment: Aside from the excellent commentary from @VadimB, you must also not reference MobileServiceClient until after the page is loaded. - I'm not an Ionic expert, but I believe referencing in the callback from $ionicPlatform.ready() is suitable.